# Marklogic ml-gradle not clearing the database

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

I have recently loaded about 30GB of data to a database. To clear the content I ran the following gradle command which succeeded but the database was not cleared. Could not find any errors in the log.

```
gradle mlClearContentDatabase -PdeleteAll=true
```

Any idea to what the issue might be or anyone have similar issues?

Comment: marklogic v is 9

Answer (score 2):

Use the project property `confirm=true`

## [Clearing the content database](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Common-tasks#clearing-the-content-database)

```
gradle mlClearContentDatabase -Pconfirm=true
```

It looks like the wiki page might be incorrect. Says you should use `deleteAll` instead of `confirm`.

> You must include the property `-PdeleteAll=true`, which is required to decrease the chance that you run this task accidentally.

Comment: That's correct - the example has the right property (confirm=true), the explanation did not. I fixed that. Also note that if confirm=true is not included, the task throws an error stating it must be incldued.

Comment: I just tried  gradle mlClearContentDatabase -Pconfirm=true and got a message  To clear the database, include the deleteAll parameter e.g. -PdeleteAll=true using mlgradle version 3.0.0